# Ubuntu 17.04 - Apple Magic Mouse 2 Scrolling Not Working

Tags: mouse, 17.04, apple, mouse-scroll

I am running Ubuntu 17.04 (kernel: 4.10.0-35-generic) and the "touch" scrolling is not working on my **Apple Magic Mouse 2** and never has been.

I have been doing research and I can't find anything that seems to resolves this (at least nothing that resolves it for me using the current kernel).

When I run `xinput --list` I can see my mouse (id = 21).

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer DeathStalker                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer DeathStalker                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL06E4:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad             id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Rascal’s Mouse                            id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer DeathStalker                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer DeathStalker                  id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 04:52:C7:61:D3:31                         id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Using this ID, I can view the device's props using `xinput --list-props 21`.

```
Device 'Rascal’s Mouse':
Device Enabled (142):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Accel Speed (283): -0.700000
libinput Accel Speed Default (284): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (285):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (286):   1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (287):   1, 0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (279):   1
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (280):   0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (264): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (265):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (266):    0, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (288): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (289): 0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (290):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (291):   0, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (292):   0, 0, 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button (293): 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (294): 0
Device Node (267):  "/dev/input/event19"
Device Product ID (268):    76, 617
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (281):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (282):   1
```

I can see that **libinput Scroll Methods Available (290)** is set to `0, 0, 1` and yet **libinput Scroll Method Enabled (291)** is set to `0, 0, 0` so I figured changing this via `xinput --set-prop 21 291 0 0 1` might make the scroll kick in. It didn't seem to make any difference though.

On a side note, scrolling works on my touchpad fine (that's two-finger scrolling though, not quite the same as the Magic Mouse's single finger scroll but I don't know if that makes a difference).

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to how I might be able to get the scrolling working?

Cheers

Comment: For anybody coming across this post in the future...I unfortunately did **not** find a solution to get the Magic Mouse scrolling working. I am just back using a basic USB mouse for now.

Comment: If you'd like some people have come up with a clever solution [here](https://github.com/rohitpid/Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver)
And It's totally working for me on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

it almost works for me with ubuntu 18.04.

kernel 4.15.0-13-generic
module mac_hid

```
Device Enabled (142):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (277):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (278):   0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (279):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (280):   0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (281):   0, 0, 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button (282): 3
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (283): 3
libinput Accel Speed (284): -0.237410
libinput Accel Speed Default (285): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (286):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (287):   1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (288):   1, 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (262): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (263):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (264):    0, 0
Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event22"
Device Product ID (266):    76, 617
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (291):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (292):   1
```

`libinput Scroll Method Enabled (280):   0, 0, 1` initially was `0, 0, 0`. After changing to `0, 0, 1` clicking and holding right button enables scroll by moving the mouse

Comment: You are right, it does work better in **18.04**. It's a bit weird having to hold down the right button to scroll but I'll see how I get on with it.

Cheers for pointing this out.

Comment: I have the same issue with Magic Mouse 2. You can also change to scroll by clicking and holding left button by *xinput --set-prop 9 293 1*. Interesting point is that on Magic Mouse (old one without lightning) it has *libinput Button Scrolling Button (282): 2* and works the same as in Mac OS without holding any buttons.